# Where can I read Sridhara Swami's commentary on the Srimad Bhagavatam online?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, resource

I would want to read Sridhara Swami's commentary of the Srimad Bhagavatam online in English. Can anyone of you provide me the relevant pdf or link?

Comment: His commentary on Bhagavatam has never been translated into English.  But S. Subbarao's translation of the Bhagavatam contains summaries of what Sridhara Swami (and two other commentators) say about various verses in the Bhagavatam.  Also, Sridhara Swami's commentary on the Bhagavad Gita has been translated into English.

Comment: @Sarvabhaouma,its available in hindi

Comment: His commentary has been used along with other commentators , individually there is no translation of his commentary.

Comment: The translation of Sridhara Swami's Bhavartha Dipika commentary on Srimad Bhagavatam is available in hindi language, but it is nor available online for free.

Answer (score 2):

The first canto's translation by Mohendra Natha Chaterjee is available here: https://www.scribd.com/document/117742348/Canto-1-of-Srimad-Bhagavatam-with-3-Commentaries

Comment: Is the Sridhara Swamin commentary available with Hindi translation?  If yes, pl. give details. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, by Motilal banarasidas. Available in hard copy