# Is the commentary on Bhagavatam by Sridhara Swami available?

Tags: bhagavata-purana, commentary

Is Sridhara Swami's commentary on Bhagavatam available now
in English or Telugu?

Is the Gita Press translation of the Bhagavatam based on Sridhara Swami's commentary?

Comment: Is [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shreedhar_Swami) the Shridhara Swami you are talking about?

Comment: Not puri shridhara swami

Comment: Sridhara Svami (1378-1414) wrote the oldest complete Srimad-Bhagavatam commentary, called Bhavartha-dipika.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Where can I read Sridhara Swami's commentary on the Srimad Bhagavatam online?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/21792/where-can-i-read-sridhara-swamis-commentary-on-the-srimad-bhagavatam-online)